# User Login With AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am building my first iOS app.

I have got the backend code done, but I am struggling with the Objective-C part of it.

I have a signup / login page.

But I don't know how to send that data to my server using Objective C.

I have read that AFNetworking is good, but I was wondering how I could use that for user login .

I have downloaded  and added AFNetworking to my XCode Project and set up headers.

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://examplewebsite.com]];

[client setDefaultHeader:@"key" value:@"value"];
[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];
[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:@"token"];

NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"someMethod" path:@"somePath" parameters:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
```

but I am still lost.

Comment: Are you trying to do http auth, or are you trying to login to your own rest api?

Comment: I am trying to login to my own API

Comment: I am really new to this - i have done one web app before. I am trying to use my backend code to create a user login experience on the iPhone

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to login to your own API, you don't want setAuthorization stuff.  That's for basic HTTP auth.  Instead you want to use [getPath:parameters:success:failure](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/getPath%3aparameters%3asuccess%3afailure%3a) or the postPath version, depending on if your backend is expecting HTTP GET or HTTP POST.

Pass your userid / password in the parameters argument.  You should set [parameterEncoding](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/parameterEncoding) to be the correct format.  You're probably using HTTP Forms url encoding, or JSON.  Whatever your backend expects.

Comment: Can you provide us a link where is described how username and password format should look like when sending them in parameters object of getPath:parameters:success:failure method call? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to set the authorization headers in this case, since this is for "*basic access HTTP authentication*", which is a method for a HTTP user agent to provide a user name and password when making a request to a server.

You want to use your own API and interact with a restful server and therefore, I would recommend, that you [subclass AFHTTPClient ->  interact with an API, Web Service, or Application.](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) - *Take a look at the examples in the AFNetworking zip archive, if you have difficulties in subclassing AFHTTPClient.*

Since you want to create an app with user login, the app needs to send these information to your server, and the server should return if the login was succesful or not. 
This can be done like so - HTTP POST.

```
 - (void)login {

    // Login information from UITextFields
    id params = @{
        @"username": self.usernameField.text,
        @"password": self.passwordField.text
    };

    //Call the AFHTTP subclass client, with post block. postPath = the path of the url,   where the parameters should be posted. 
    [[theAuthAPIClient sharedClient] postPath:@"/login"
                                parameters:params
                                   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                                       //handle succesful response from server. 

                                   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                       // handle error - login failed
                                       }
                                   }];

}
```

You need to pass the parameters in the right format, depending on what format your server expects. This can be done by setting the right encoding in your AFHTTPClient subclass -> [ParameterEncoding](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/parameterEncoding)

Comment: Would you mind adding more detail/context to this?  It's not working for me.  I don't seem to understand the sharedClient aspect of it. I also have two NSLogs set, one for Succes, one for the Error, but neither get called. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but can you be more specific?, is it only the sharedClient that's not working/you don't understand or is it the code I provided?

Comment: The server returns application/json

However, when I used this, it still fails all the time.

Comment: The code I have posted above is to POST data to the server and not to GET and it is fully functioning (I am using the excact same code , in an app of mine). You have to be more specific, fx. where in the code does it fail etc. If you want to GET data from you server, change postPath to getPath.

Answer (score 0):

Since I came here while searching for a working solution for ***AFNetworking 2.0***, not knowing that `AFHTTPClient` was removed from the Framework, I will post the new way to establish this connection here:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://examplewebsite.com"]];
[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"userName" password:@"password"];
```