# How to login on ios device with django server?

Tags: iphone, django, authentication, tastypie

I am making an ios app that requires a webservice. The webservice will be using an already-in-place and completely unchangeable (for my purposes) database that is handled by Django. I know how to set up the UI and develop apps in general, but how do I manage the backend side / client side for login? I noticed some people talking about TastyPie when I researched the topic but I am unsure about what exactly that entails. I've been using php for the rest of the service - would using TastyPie make me write it in some other language? Is TastyPie really necessary?

Furthermore, I saw someone say that one may just put a UIWebView and then take the cookie out of it when the login. Is that feasible? It sounds like the easiest option.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tastypie is just a Python Django framework to help developers write REST APIs easily.

Yes using Tastypie will make you write APIs in Python. Tastypie is not necessary to write REST APIs.

In your case since you can not change the database. I would suggest you to write REST API in Python Django and use django.auth login method after authenticating the credentials. login method will create the session key for you. You can send back that key in response and then pass that key to all the subsequent REST API calls. Do not use Tastypie for writing this API as Tastypie will require you to add some tables in the DB.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your answer because you did not mention anything to do with the ios app. I understand how to do the login normally. How do I do this with an iphone app?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest AFNetworking as a library that is commonly used to communicate with REST services.  There should be no need to change your existing server code.  AFNetworking is on github.

There are also a ton of posts on StackOverflow about using AFNetworking.  Pertaining to the specifics of logging in - look at this [User Login With AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914577/user-login-with-afnetworking) or search further.